# Apache2: 2 virtual hosts with subdomains not working

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost

I have set up one conf file in apache with 2 virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName test.domain.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/django/test/test/wsgi.py
    <Directory /var/django/test/test>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *.80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName domain.com
    #ServerAlias *.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But unfortunately only the first one is being called no matter what domain I put into the browser.

My expectation is that only test.domain.com will open my Django project and all other subdomains use the standard website.

What did I do wrong?

Regards

Kev

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

after replacing the dot wih a ":" the it worked perfekt.